# How to add User ID index and user:references to an Items Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was creating items class. I was suppose to do

```
rails generate model Items title:string price:decimal description:text user:references
```

But I did by mistake

```
rails generate model Items title:string price:decimal description:text
```

How do I add `user:references` without deleting my the migration file? Will I need another migration file which adds `user:references`?

I will also need to add a `user_id` index to create the new migration for `user:references`. Can I just add the following code to the migration?

```
add_index :Items, [:user_id, :created_at]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try following migration:

```
rails g migration AddUserToItems user:references
```

This will create following configuration for you.

```
class AddUserToItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :items, :user, index: true
  end
end
```

Comment: I will try that. But im pretty sure that the migration file needs to have this in it as well  t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true. Very similar to this https://www.railstutorial.org/book/user_microposts but instead of a micropost its an Item.

Comment: the command will do the needful for you, you don't need to do any manual edit to the migration file content. try & update.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do it right, but your syntax isn't correct. Here's how you can accomplish it:

```
class AddUserIdToItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  add_index :items, :user_id, :integer
  # add_reference, :items, :user, index: true
  add_column :items, :created_at, :datetime
end
```

So, now you can either use `add_reference` method, or simply can use `add_index` method. `add_column` will be used to add `created_at` column as you have mentioned in your question.